# How to generate a FusionAuth API key using .Net core client library

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization, fusionauth

I am kind of new to [FusionAuth](https://fusionauth.io/). I need to generate a new API key for a newly created tenant. I was able to create new tenant using same client library but having a hard time generating API key. Following snippet shows the code I wrote for the task in hand.

```
var apiKeyCreateResponse = await authClient.CreateAPIKeyAsync(null, new APIKeyRequest
{
    apiKey = new APIKey
    {
        tenantId = tenant.id,
        permissions = new APIKeyPermissions
        {
            endpoints = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                {"/api/tenant", new List<string>{ "GET" }}
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting `404` with this code with an exception message `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

The new API key should be restricted to access `GET /api/tenant` endpoint only. Can anyone please provide some direction on this? I am not quite sure if I am constructing the `endpoints` object correctly. Any help on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

FusionAuth Client Version I am using: `1.26.0`

Comment: What version of FusionAuth are you using? It looks like 1.26? Also, you need to provide an API key with a `key manager` setting of `true` to call this API. Such a key must be created in the fusionauth admin UI and can't create any keys with permissions greater than it. (So for your example, must have the `/api/tenant` GET permission.)

Comment: @mooreds I am currently using FusionAuth Client version 1.26.0. I am creating auth client as ```var authClient = new FusionAuthClient(apiKey, host);```. ```apiKey``` provided is the super key with all the permissions. Regargind ```key manager``` setting, I am not sure where that can be configured. I did not see any such setting in Fusion Auth admin console.

Comment: Hi @mahesh, you need to create a key manager. You can do so in the admin interface. You can only do so with new api keys. Here's an image which shows this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TYuvIPJy9OVJ5ui1TrIDkkZWWzPSwdI2/view?usp=sharing